# How to exchange variables between different python files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-import

I've 2 python files file1.py and file2.py in the same directory.

```py
#file1.py

import file2 as f2

graph={ 0: [1,2],
        1: [0,3,2,4],
        2: [0,4,3,1],
        3: [1,2,5],
        4: [2,1,5],
        5: [4,3]
      }

def function1(graph):
   print(f2.C1)
```

The other file is

```py
#file2.py

import file1 as f1

graph=f1.graph

def function2(graph):

#Perform some operation on graph to return a dictionary C

    return C


C1=function2(graph)
```

When I run file1, I'm getting an error

```py
module 'file2' has no attribute 'C1'
```

And when I run file2 and try to check the value of C1 variable, I'm getting an error:

```
module 'file1' has no attribute 'graph'
```

What should I do to import these files correctly so as to exchange the values between the files appropriately?

Note that when I implement the variable graph in file2 directly instead of fetching from file1, it works perfectly, but it starts creating an issue when the variables are exchanged between the files.

Edited:

I've added more refined version of the code to simplify the problem.

```py
#file1

import file2 as f2

def fun1(graph):
   C=[None]*20
    for i in range(20):
        # Some algorithm to generate the subgraphs s=[s1,s2,...,s20]
        C[i]=f2.fun2(s[i]) 
        print(C[i])



graph={ 0: [1,2],
        1: [0,3,2,4],
        2: [0,4,3,1],
        3: [1,2,5],
        4: [2,1,5],
        5: [4,3]
      } 

def getGraph():
    return graph

fun1(graph)
```

Other file file2.py

```
import file1 as f1


graph_local=f1.getGraph()

#Some operations on graph_local to generate another graph 'graph1' of same "type" as graph_local

def fun2(graph1):

   #Perform some operation on graph1 to return a dictionary C

    return C
```

If I create a test.py as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55705055/7447425),

```py
#test.py

from file1 import fun1

fun1(None)
```

When I run test.py or file2.py, the error is

```
module 'file1' has no attribute 'getGraph'
```

whereas when I run file1.py,

```
module 'file2' has no attribute 'C'
```

Comment: If file1 really imports file2 and file2 imports file1 you have a circular import and should fix this design issue first. Other than that, consider passing objects as function parameters instead of working with global variables.

Comment: @andreihondrari Saving the value in a file and reading it from another is generating the above error

Comment: From what you have posted, the variable `graph` which is a `dict` should actually be located in `file2.py`. This would solve your circular imports.

Comment: @quamrana If it was present in file2, then there wouldn't be any issue. What I have posted is a simplified version of the code and for design constraints, it quite necessary that 'graph' should be in file1 and be passed into file2 and the value extracted back to file1. Is there a way of doing that? Any other suggestions are welcome. :)

Comment: Any reason why graph definition can't be in file3, included from both file1 and file2?

Comment: @Amadan I will do that if I don't get any answer in this way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @YourIDE: Does my answer give you any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid global variables that are constructed upon import.

Below I have used functions as accessors which delay the resolution of symbols:

test.py:

```
from file1 import function1

function1(None)
```

file1.py

```
import file2

# I have retained graph here
graph={ 0: [1,2],
        1: [0,3,2,4],
        2: [0,4,3,1],
        3: [1,2,5],
        4: [2,1,5],
        5: [4,3]
      }

def getGraph():
    return graph
def function1(graph):
   print(file2.getC1())
```

file2.py

```
import file1 as f1

# graph=f1.getGraph()

def function2(graph):
    graph[6]='Added more'
    #Perform some operation on graph to return a dictionary C

    return graph


def getC1():
    return function2(f1.getGraph())
```

When I run test.py I get this output:

```
{0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 3, 2, 4], 2: [0, 4, 3, 1], 3: [1, 2, 5], 4: [2, 1, 5], 5: [4, 3], 6: 'Added more'}
```

Comment: I've updated the question along with the code. Thank you for the help.